# Is a try-catch block a reliable way to use the `in` operator?

Tags: javascript

The [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) can only be used on non-primitive values. Attempting to use the `in` operator on a primitive throws a TypeError.

Example function:

```js
function isFoo(value) {
  return value && 'foo' in value;
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'foo' in *primitive value*

There are several ways to avoid this issue:

1. **Type checking**
   This approach seems the most proper, as it formalizes the fact that primitives are invalid. But it's lengthy.

```js
function isFoo(value) {
  const type = typeof value;

  return value
    && type !== 'string'
    && type !== 'number'
    && type !== 'boolean'
    && 'foo' in value;
}
```

2. **Typecasting**
   This approach is shorter than the last and accomplishes the same job, but adds performance overhead.

```js
function isFoo(value) {
  const obj = Object(value);

  return value && 'foo' in obj;
}
```

3. **hasOwnProperty**
   This approach doesn't use the `in` operator at all and, instead, uses the `hasOwnProperty` method which is available on primitives. But it's longer.

```js
function isFoo(value) {
  return value && value.hasOwnProperty('foo');
}
```

However, I'd like to know if this final approach, of using a try-catch block, is reliable or proper.

**try ... catch**

```js
function isFoo(value) {
  try {
    return value && 'foo' in value;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
```

It's my worry that, for example, some JS implementations may not throw a catchable exception on the misuse of the `in` operator. I'm also not sure if purposely allowing TypeError exceptions has a performance impact.

Is it unwise to use the try-catch approach?

Comment: JavaScript does not support type casting. `Object(value)` is not type casting, it creates an object of the correct type for the primitive value. All primitive types can be expressed using literals but there are also types for them that extend `Object`. The documentation explains: *"When called in a non-constructor context, Object behaves identically to new Object()."* -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Description

Comment: Typecasting is the intent of the example, though, so that feels like an unnecessary nitpick.

Comment: how about `const isObject = value => typeof value === "object" && value!==null, isFoo = value => isObject(value) && 'foo' in value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of best practices, if you use exceptions appropriately (i.e. only in genuinely exceptional or unexpected error situations) then they're unlikely to be a significant performance hit and are completely acceptable.

But in your case, relying on a try-catch block for control flow could incur significant time costs on your program, despite it achieving the desired output, and as such is not considered the optimal approach.

I'd recommend using one of the earlier methods you mentioned instead, likely the first one.